import statement in javascript
I have html code with javascript inside a django project:
<body>
<-- some html>
</body>
<script>
import fs from "fs"
// some javascript
</script>

Now I get the error import declarations may only appear at the top level of a module.
What am I doing wrong? And is there some reference that explains how the import works in javascript? I'm not used to javascript yet and in all other languages I never had an issue with import statements.

a) you need <script type="module"> but b) you can't import nodejs module in a browser

By default, <script> tags are interpreted as regular scripts, not as ES6 modules. Specify the script as a module using the type="module" attribute.
<body>
<-- some html>
</body>
<script type="module">
import fs from "fs";
/* fs cannot be imported in browser environment
since it is a Node.js standard lib */
// some javascript
</script>


this only partially solved the problem. Now I get an uncaught TypeError saying something like specifiers "fs" have to start with "./", "../" or "/" which in turn gives me a MIME type error.

It's because "fs" module is part of the Node.js standard library and does not work in the browser environment.

</body> //use this approch <script type="module"> import fs from "fs"
//YOUR CODE HERE

//or either use this
`<script type="commonjs">
    const fs = require('fs')`
</script>

